# Flutter Android existing host app which extends Fragment/AppCompatActivity ,onClick of button need to send a message to Flutter Dart

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have an existing Android app and added flutter module to it as a library by following this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps).

I have an existing fragment which extends Fragment and wants to send a message from this fragment to Dart using the channel.
following this [link](https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/creating-a-bridge-in-flutter-between-dart-and-native-code-in-java-or-objectivec-5f80fd0cd713) for that :

Added this code to my existing Fragment on click of a button and an error I get is "**Cannot resolve method getFlutterView()**"

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                    if (call.method.equals("helloFromNativeCode")) {
                        String greetings = helloFromNativeCode();
                        result.success(greetings);
                    }
                }
            });

}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to fix it by adding dummy FlutterView,

```
View flutterView = Flutter.createView(
            MainActivity.this,
            getLifecycle(),
            "anyText"
    );

    new MethodChannel((BinaryMessenger) flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                    if (call.method.equals("helloFromNativeCode")) {
                        String greetings = helloFromNativeCode();
                        result.success(greetings);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the extent **AppCompatActivity** IN flutter you need to extend it with the **FlutterActivity** after that it works, Below is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
private static final String CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                    if (call.method.equals("helloFromNativeCode")) {
                        String greetings = helloFromNativeCode();
                        result.success(greetings);
                    }
                }
            });

}
}
```

Comment: my existing code is already written with AppCompatActivity, So can't change to FlutterActivity.

Comment: But getFlutterView() method available only in FlutterActivity. You can change it and try once